# Lua - Creating a user driven menu - terminal interface - how best to navigate?

Tags: lua

I’ve been trying to build a user driven interface (at the terminal level) where I can create a menu of options to choose a specific Lua script to run. However while I can do some things I can’t work out a way to bounce back up within the script to present earlier menu options.

See script below. (The commented section is where I’m stuck , but I would welcome any advice about the whole approach )

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

local term = require ("term") --https://luarocks.org/modules/hoelzro/lua-term
term.clear()
print "-------------------------------------------------"
print "|               My Lua Script Menu              |"
print "-------------------------------------------------"
print"[00] Weather Report Emails"
print"[01] Energy Report Emails"
print"[02] Camera Screenshot Emails"
print"[03] TBC"
print"[Exit]
print "-------------------------------------------------"
io.write("Section: ")
local pass = io.read()

if pass == "00" then
    
    term.clear()
    print "-------------------------------------------------"
    print "|            Weather Report Emails              |"
    print "-------------------------------------------------"
    print "Information about the scripts to go here"
    print ""
    print"[A] 12hr Weather Report Email"
    print"[B] 24hr Weather Report Email"
    print"[C] 3 Day Weather Report Email"
    print"[D] 7 Day Weather Report Email"
    print ""
    io.write("Section: ")
    local pass = io.read()
        if pass == "A" then dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameA.lua") end
        if pass == "B" then dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameB.lua") end
        if pass == "C" then dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameC.lua") end
        if pass == "D" then dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameD.lua") end
    print "Press X to return to main menu or Y to return to previous menu ]"
    local pass = io.read()
        -- if pass == "X" then << what goes here to go to the main menu >> end
        -- if pass == "Y" then << what goes here to go to the previous menu>> end
        term.clear()
    end
end

if pass == "01" then
    term.clear()
    print "-------------------------------------------------"
    print "|            Energy Report Emails               |"
    print "-------------------------------------------------"
    print "Information about the scripts to go here"
    print ""
    print"[A] 12hr Energy Report Email"
    print"[B] 24hr Energy Report Email"
    print"[C] 3 Day Energy Report Email"
    print"[D] 7 Day Energy Report Email"
    print ""
    io.write("Section: ")
    local pass = io.read()
        if pass == "A" then dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameA1.lua") end
        if pass == "B" then dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameB1.lua") end
        if pass == "C" then dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameC1.lua") end
        if pass == "D" then dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameD1.lua") end
    print "Press X to return to main menu or Y to return to previous menu ]"
    local pass = io.read()
        -- if pass == "X" then << what goes here to go to the main menu >> end
        -- if pass == "Y" then << what goes here to go to the previous menu>> end
        term.clear()
    end
end

if pass == "02" then
    term.clear()
    print "-------------------------------------------------"
    print "|          Camera Screenshot Emails             |"
    print "-------------------------------------------------"
    print "Information about the scripts to go here"
    print ""
    print"[A] 1 Snapshot email"
    print"[B] 2 Snapshot email"
    print"[C] 3 Snapshot email"
    print"[D] 4 Snapshot email"
    print ""
    io.write("Section: ")
    local pass = io.read()
        if pass == "A" then dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameA1A.lua") end
        if pass == "B" then dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameB1B.lua") end
        if pass == "C" then dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameC1C.lua") end
        if pass == "D" then dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameD1D.lua") end
    print "Press X to return to main menu or Y to return to previous menu ]"
    local pass = io.read()
        -- if pass == "X" then << what goes here to go to the main menu >> end
        -- if pass == "Y" then << what goes here to go to the previous menu>> end
        term.clear()
    end
end

if pass == "03" then
    term.clear()
    print "-------------------------------------------------"
    print "|                      TBC                      |"
    print "-------------------------------------------------"
    print "Information about the scripts to go here"
    print ""
    print "    [Press enter to return to main menu]"
    local pass = io.read()
    
    if pass == "" then
        term.clear()
        print("03 - i would reboot here???")
    end
end


if pass == "Exit" then
    print("i would need to exist out somehow here???")
    —-how best do I just exist out here.
    term.clear()
else
    print("Please select one of the optjons ")
end

-- lua home/pi/shared/selection_menu_v1.lua
-- sudo chmod +x home/pi/shared/selection_menu_v1.lua
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would put the menu code into a function you could actually reuse it. All you had to do to get back to main menu is to call the function that handles the main menu.

Simple example:

```
function mainMenu()
  
  print("main menu")
  print("[1] submenu 1")
  print("[x] exit")
  
  return handleInput{
    ["1"] = subMenu1,
    ["x"] = os.exit,
  }

end

function subMenu1()
  
  print("submenu 1")
  print("[b] back")
  
  return handleInput{
    ["b"] = mainMenu,
  }
  
end

function handleInput(options)
   local input
  repeat input = io.read() until options[input]

  return options[input]() 
    
end

mainMenu()
```

In Lua >= 5.2 you could also use the `goto` statements to back and forth in your code.

Comment: Unless you want to eventually run out of stack, you need to employ tail calls at end of your function.

Comment: Hi @OlegV.Volkov, please could you post an update on what you mean ?

Comment: Hi @piglet, thanks for this, but forgive the question where do I put the dofile actions ? I added options in each sub-menu but they run automatically when the sub menu is choose . handleInput{
    ["z"] = mainMenu,
 ["A"] = dofile("home/pi/shared/TS_cabin_graph_watts_24h.lua"),
 ["B"] = dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameB.lua"),
    ["C"] = dofile("home/pi/shared/filenameC.lua"),
    ["x"] = function () os.exit() end
  }

Comment: @nodecentral you put the dofile where you want to use dofile. I don't understand your question. let's say you want to run some file if a key is pressed in subMenu1 you add it to the inputHandler in subMenu1

Comment: @Piglet I think I’ve got it working now, thanks so much - I’ve posted the answer below. Let me know if you would do anything differently.

Comment: @nodecentral it is fixed by Piglet in edit to an answer already - check the history to see added returns.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, below is what I ended up with, currently only the first one is populated..

````
#!/usr/bin/lua

local term = require ("term") --https://luarocks.org/modules/hoelzro/lua-term

function mainMenu()
term.clear()
print "-------------------------------------------------"
print "|               My Lua Script Menu              |"
print "-------------------------------------------------"
print"[0] Weather Report Emails"
print"[1] Energy Report Emails"
print"[2] Camera Screenshot Emails"
print"[3] TBC"
print"[x] Exit"
print "-------------------------------------------------"
io.write("Selection: ")
    handleInput{
    ["0"] = subMenu0,
    ["1"] = subMenu1,
    ["2"] = subMenu2,
    ["3"] = subMenu3,
    ["x"] = function () os.exit() end
  }
end

function subMenu0()
    term.clear()
    print "-------------------------------------------------"
    print "|            Weather Report Emails              |"
    print "-------------------------------------------------"
    print "Information about the scripts to go here"
    print ""
    print"[a] 12hr Weather Report Email"
    print"[b] 24hr Weather Report Email"
    print"[c] 3 Day Weather Report Email"
    print"[d] 7 Day Weather Report Email"
    print"[z] Return to the main menu"
    print"[x] Exit"
    print ""
    io.write("Selection: ")
handleInput{
    ["z"] = mainMenu,
    ["a"] = function () dofile("home/pi/shared/TS_cabin_graph_watts_12h.lua") subMenu0() end,
    ["b"] = function () dofile("home/pi/shared/TS_cabin_graph_watts_24h.lua") subMenu0() end,
    ["c"] = function () dofile("home/pi/shared/TS_cabin_graph_watts_3d.lua") subMenu0() end,
    ["c"] = function () dofile("home/pi/shared/TS_cabin_graph_watts_7d.lua") subMenu0() end,
    ["x"] = function () os.exit() end
  }
end

function subMenu1()
  
  print("submenu 1")
  print("[b] back")
  
  handleInput{
    ["b"] = mainMenu,
  }
  
end

function subMenu2()
  
  print("submenu 2")
  print("[b] back")
  
  handleInput{
    ["b"] = mainMenu,
  }
  
end

function subMenu3()
  
  print("submenu 3")
  print("[b] back")
  
  handleInput{
    ["b"] = mainMenu,
  }
  
end

function handleInput(options)
   local input
  repeat input = io.read() until options[input]

  options[input]() 
    
end

mainMenu()
```
````